# password reset with configuration SMTP

Tags: django, email

This is my SMTP configuration for my web page.

#SMTP (Simple Mail Transfert Protocole) Configuration

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****************'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*************'
```

I created a web page using python and Django where the user has to login before.
When the user has forgotten his password, he has the possibility to reset his password.
to reset his password, the user has to enter his email then the link will be sent to his email provided during his registration.

****but when the user enters his email then clicks on send, instead to send the link into his email account, the link is redirect/ sent,  to the "EMAIL_HOST_USER".****

Problem/Error
*How should I configure the SMTP (Simple Mail Transfert Protocole) so that the user receives the link of the password reset into his email account provided during his registration?

please help me.*

Comment: Please share the code for the password reset view that is calling ```send_mail``` and doing the actual email sending. All we can see right now is settings :)

Comment: @Twrought, I'm user the Django In-built function to reset the password of the user.
By doing that, we have to configure the SMTP in the setting.